# Email Template Greeting message issue

Tags: email-template

My requirement is when a new User is Created an Email is to sent that new created Users Email address with message Welcome UserfirstName + UserLastName. For that, I created a HTML Email Template and a letterhead with this template. Template Body Contains. 
'Welcome {!User.FirstName} {!User.LastName}'
I have written a workflow rules, but when new User is Created that receives the Email with current User FirstName+ LastName.
Like if current user is system admin and i created a new user with Name 'Raj sinha'.Then Raj sinha receives an Email with body 'Welcome System admin' not 'Welcome Raj Sinha'. 
How to achieve it is there any idea please help.

Comment: Can you please post the body of your email template and update the question?

Comment: Body:  Welcome  {!User.FirstName} {!User.LastName}                                                   I have created a new user with name raj sinha  and the workflow is that when new user is created then he receives an email with welcome message and new user name. But according thus way he receives an email with welcome message and name is system admin.

Answer (score 0):

Into your email template try to use `{!Receiving_User.FirstName}` instead of `{!User.FirstName}`